# Show scrollbar when table content doesn't fit in div height Boostrap CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm doing a page that uses Boostrap, looks like this:

[image]

At the right side I have this two tables inside a div, the problem is that when the tables contains too much elements, grows in height, but I want the table to show a vertical scrollbar.

Here's the problem:

[image]

The code looks like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- ********** Tauler ********** -->
        <div id="board" class="col-sm-6 board m-3 shadow">
            <!-- Crea desde board JS -->
        </div>
        <!-- ********** Llistat de moviments ********** -->
        <div id="move-list" class="col-sm-2 m-3 bg-light shadow">
            <table class="table table-striped caption-top">
                <caption class="text-center fw-bold">Llistat de moviments</caption>
                <thead class="table-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th id="light-player-name" scope="col">Jugador 1</th>
                    <th id="dark-player-name" scope="col">Jugador 2</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>♙f3</td>
                    <td>♟︎e5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>♘cr</td>
                    <td>♞c6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>♙f4</td>
                    <td>♟︎exf4</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- ********** Llistat de jugadors ********** -->
        <div id="online-list" class="col-sm-2 m-3 bg-light shadow">
            <table class="table table-striped caption-top">
                <caption class="text-center fw-bold">Llistat de jugadors en línea</caption>
                <thead class="table-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nom d'usuari</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>@username</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>@username</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>@username</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your `<table class="table table-striped caption-top">` a style.

Like `<table class="table table-striped caption-top" style="overflow-y:scroll;">`

or, using bootstrap, `<table class="table table-striped caption-top overflow-auto">`.

Bootsrap doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/overflow/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).